Why are most philosophers moral realists?
I’m having trouble understanding this. Moral realism is the position that morality is independent of subjective opinion. But how can this be if only we care about what’s moral? Lions are ripping other animals’ heads off and nature doesn’t care. So why should we?
Any argument that I’ve seen for moral realism seems to beg the question and yet I see 50+% of philosophers still believing it. I can’t seem to even think of a way to make this make sense. Can someone enlighten me if I’m missing out? This kind of reminds me of how there are scientists that say certain particles don’t have objective attributes until you measure them, such as in quantum mechanics. To this day, I haven’t seen an argument that explains what they mean. How can reality not be objective?
So what do people mean when they say that moral facts are independent of subjective opinion?

"Lions are ripping other animals’ heads off and nature doesn’t care. " Humans are killing each others and nature doesn's care...

Indeed, so what is the justification for being a moral realist?

@Marriott it seems to me there's some disconnect of intuition between most (non-theistic) moral realists and moral non realists. I would argue that most moral realists and non realists agree on almost all relevant questions surrounding morality, but then regardless of that agreement they disconnect at some particular concept which each party interprets differently.

@TKoL To me it’s like chocolate. Everyone likes chocolate. But no sane person on earth would say that this is objective

Tom Holland is a good starting point

Math doesn't care if you have extra money or are in debt, but having extra money is better.

@Marriott Chocolate realists are chocolate realists, not because they think that liking chocolate is necessary, but because they believe that chocolate is what it is whether people like it or not. Moral realists think that the right thing to do is like chocolate, not like liking chocolate.

@Marriott Of course liking chocolate is objective, it triggers specific neurochemistry in our brain, plus glucose is a desired source of energy evolutionary. So what you call "liking" on the data level is a coded positive reinforcement to eat more.
